# Add code to Bookdown gitbook template before TOC

Tags: r, templates, banner, bookdown, gitbook

I'm creating a gitbook using bookdown, and the designer wants to put a banner at the top of the book, that is, across the entire page above both the TOC and the chapter text.

If I use the **before_body** attribute in the YAML, bookdown inserts the code after the TOC, so the banner is only at the top of the chapter. Gitbook doesn't seem to allow for the **template:** attribute.

Any suggestions for how I can squeeze a line of HTML right after the < body > tag to make my designer happy? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself--it turns out that although officially the gitbook theme doesn't allow the **template:** attribute, in practice it does. So I just grabbed the existing template, hard-coded my banner after the < body > tag, and referenced my new template in the YAML. I hope this is helpful for anybody else who runs into this problem!